# Excel function to extract string from a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns with just strings in them:

A1:  tomatoes

A2:  peas

A3:  potatoes

In the column next to them, I want to have the length of each corresponding string. Instead of =LEN("tomatoes"), I want something like =LEN(AS_STRING(A1)). Does Excel have any functionality like this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the cell reference

`=LEN(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

=LEN(A1) and then drag the formula down to get the LEN for the other words . I hope this r